# Google y Facebook OAuth con Express, Passport y Typescript

Tags: nodejs, express, passport

actualmente tengo un login desarollado con Typescript, Express, Passport y JWT pero quiero integrar para registrar y logear usuarios con Facebook y Google.

Estuve revisando la documentación de http://www.passportjs.org/ y la verdad es que estoy un poco perdido y no se lograrlo, al menos con typescript.

Quisiera ver como realmente integro ambos sistemas de logeo y como puedo validarlos también, he visto vídeos y algunos tutoriales pero son antiguos y no puedo hacerlo bien

Muchas gracias si me pueden ayudar

Voy a dejarles los archivos generados en mi backend:

user.controller.ts

```
import {Request, Response} from 'express';
import User, {IUser} from '../models/user';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import config from '../config/config'

function createToken(user: IUser) {
   return jwt.sign({id: user.id, email: user.email}, config.jwtSecret, {
      expiresIn: 86400
   });
}

export const registrar = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> => {
   if (!req.body.email || !req.body.password) {
      return res.status(400).json({msg: 'Por favor envia tu correo y contraseña'});
   }
   const user = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email});
   if (user) {
      return res.status(400).json({msg: 'El usuario ya existe'});
   }

   const newUser = new User(req.body);
   await newUser.save();

   return res.status(201).json(newUser);
}

export const conectar = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> => {
   if (!req.body.email || !req.body.password) {
      return res.status(400).json({msg: 'Por favor envia tu correo y contraseña'});
   }

   const user = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email});

   if (!user) {
      return res.status(400).json({msg: 'El usuario no existe'});
   }

   const isMatch = await user.comparePassword(req.body.password);

   if (isMatch) {
      return res.status(200).json({token: createToken(user) });
   }

   return res.status(400).json({msg: 'El correo o la contraseña son incorrectos'});
}
```

passport.ts

```
import {Strategy, ExtractJwt, StrategyOptions} from 'passport-jwt'
import config from '../config/config';
import User from '../models/user';
import passport from 'passport';
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;

const opts: StrategyOptions = {
   jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
   secretOrKey: config.jwtSecret
}

export default new Strategy(opts, async (payload, done) => {
   try {
      const user = await User.findById(payload.id);
      if (user) {
         return done(null, user);
      }
   return done(null, false);
   } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
   }

});
```

models/user.ts

```
import { model, Schema, Document } from 'mongoose';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

export interface IUser extends Document {
   email: string;
   password: string;
   comparePassword: (password: string) => Promise<boolean>;
}

const userSchema = new Schema({
   email: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      required: true,
      lowercase: true,
      trim: true
   },
   password: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   }
});

userSchema.pre<IUser>('save', async function (next) {
   const user = this;
   if(!user.isModified('password')) return next();

   const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
   const hash = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);
   user.password = hash;
   next();

});

userSchema.methods.comparePassword = async function (password: string): Promise<boolean> {
   return await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
}

export default model<IUser>('User', userSchema);
```

app.ts

```
import express from 'express';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import cors from 'cors';
import authRoutes from './routes/auth.routes';
import privateRoutes from './routes/private.routes';
import passport from 'passport';
import passportMiddleware from './middlewares/passport';

// Inicializaciones
const app = express();

// Configuraciones
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

// Middlewares
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(passport.initialize());
passport.use(passportMiddleware);

// Rutas
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.send(`El api esta en http://localhost:${app.get('port')}`);
});

app.use(authRoutes);
app.use(privateRoutes);

export default app;
```

Comment: Para usar Google (o Facebook) como servicio de confianza para la autenticación de usuarios, no solo basta con importar la librería de Passport. Debes tener un `id` de aplicación y un `token` o `key` que te proveen tanto Google como Facebook en sus respectivos portales para desarrolladores. Una vez tengas estos datos, implementar la lógica para usar `OAuth` u `OAuth2` es relativamente sencillo con Passport (e incluso sólo con Express). ¿Ya tienes tu `id` y tu `token` o `key`? Saludos

Comment: Hola si los tengo ambos pero no se escribir el código de la documentación de Passport OAuth2 en Typescript

Comment: Bien, creo que puedo ayudarte. Veré si para mañana puedo preparar una respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Aún no consigo solucionarlo alguien más?